# I am trying to make a program that lets the user guesss a random # 1 - 100 and it will tell them higher or lower until the get it

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that lets the user guess a random # 1 - 100 and it will tell them higher or lower until the get it.

This is what I have so far. I don't know what to do from here.
public class HighLow
    {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random log = new Random();    

      //1 - 100
      int number = (log.nextInt(100) + 1);


      System.out.println("Guess?");
      int guess = keyboard.nextInt();

      if (guess == number) 
      {
          System.out.println("Congratulations!");
      }
      while (guess != number)
      {
       if  (guess > number)
       {
            System.out.println("The number is lower than that.");
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();

       }
       if (guess < number)
       {
            System.out.println("The number is higher than that.");
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();

       }
       if (guess == number) 
       {
          System.out.println("Congratulations!");
       }
      }


        }//end of main


}//end of class



}//end of class
```

Comment: You're getting there. Think more about how long you should let the user continue to guess. Right now, a user can guess a number as long as it's higher than the target. Then, they can guess a number as long as it's lower than the target. But that can easily go wrong. Let's say the target is 50. I initially guess 49, which is lower, so the first loop ends. Then I guess 57, which is higher, so the second loop ends. I still haven't guessed the actual number! What you really want to do is to loop *while the guess isn't equal to the target*.

Comment: You should test for `guess != number` in your `while` loop. Then customise the message with an `if`. When the loop ends, it's game over.

Comment: You will run into infinite loops in your code, because you have redefined `guess` inside the `while` loop, and separated the checks for whether or not `guess` is greater than or smaller than a number. The `guess` used as the while loop condition is not the same as the `int guess` you create inside the loop. hint hint ;)

Comment: You only need one `if`. Think about it.

Comment: I suggest you test the program and use the debugger if it doesn't behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need a main loop that checks whether the current guess is right or not, and an if statement that decides on the higher or lower bit. Currently your two separate while loops will not do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have two loops, but just one. You want your game to stop when the guess is **equal** to the number, so make that your ending condition:

```
while (guess != number)
```

Then, in the loop, test if the guess is greater or lower than the number, print the appropriate message, and read the next guess. If the loop ends, it means that the user found the number.

EDIT : To avoid the repetitions:

```
System.out.println("Guess?");
int guess = keyboard.nextInt();
while (guess != number) {
    if (guess > number) {
        System.out.println("The number is lower than that.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The number is higher than that.");
    }
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Congratulations!");
```

Comment: How do i make it read the next guess without making a new int class 99 times?

Comment: Just like you're doing it now, in each of your two loops.

Comment: I want it to be able to overwrite the existing "guess" interger. When I do what you said, it says int guess is already deinfed in the main.

Comment: Yes. Just keep only one of your two loops. Replace its ending condition with guess != number. And before calling "guess = keyboard.nextInt();", print the appropriate error message. You should just remove the "int" type declaration before "guess = keyboard.nextInt();". The variable is already declared before the loop. No need to re-declare it again.

Comment: What I have so far is now in the post.

Comment: Remove "int" before "guess = keyboard.nextInt();". You're redeclaring an already declared variable.

Comment: @user1038113 You're moving in the right direction, but you're forgetting to remove the `int` declaration before `guess` inside the `if` statements. The reason this is not necessary is because what you are currently doing is declaring a new `int` named `guess` that exists only inside the `if` statement you're declaring it in and it's hiding the `int` named `guess` that you declared outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: okay, i updated it now. It doesn't say congratulations after its guessed though.

Comment: @user now you can accept the answer that is most helpful to you

Comment: @user1038113 : you have a lot of repetitions here. The congratulations message should be displayed only once, after the loop: if the loop ends, it means that guess == number. And the scond if in the loop should be replaced by an else. And you should only read the next number once in the loop, instead of repeating it in the if and in the else clause. Since you just found the answer, I'll show you in my answer.